# employ good habits in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, chatbot

How can I replace the * if and else if * in the code to make it more readable, in my real code I have more than 30 else ifs, to detect different types of file extensions and it doesn't look right

```
//get a message
client.on('message', async message => {
    //detect message with files
    if(message.hasMedia){
        //save file in variable
        let attachmentData = await message.downloadMedia();

        //know its type of extension
        //this is what i want to improve
        var extension = "";
        if (attachmentData.mimetype == "image/jpeg") 
            extension = "jpg";
        else if (attachmentData.mimetype == "image/png") 
            extension = "png";
        else if (attachmentData.mimetype == "image/gif") 
            extension = "gif";
        else if (attachmentData.mimetype == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")
            extension = "pptx"
        if (extension == "")
            return;

        //convert the file to download
        var base64Data = attachmentData.data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    }
})
```

Comment: The code you show does not actually do anything with the `extension` variable that it sets.  If you could show us what you're trying to do with it, we could suggest code in a more complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a mapping of mime type to extension and do a lookup:

```js
const extensions = {
  'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
  'image/png': 'png',
  // etc
}
```

And then do a lookup:

```js
const extension = extensions[attachmentData.mimetype];
```

There are libraries like [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) that will do this for you.

Comment: So I create a separate file, and read it through a require, I did not understand well, sorry, and also if I just found the npm package for myme.type